# Excel vba with variables and formula

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help Regarding VBA. I have a excel workbook with 2 sheets. In sheet 1, J1 cell I have a value which can vary. In sheet 2 I am running the following code to add values to cells.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim nws, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set nws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

ws.Unprotect

With nws

.Cells(1, 2).Value2 = "0"

For i = 1 To cnt1

.Cells(j, 2).Value2 = "=.Cells(i, 2).Value2+1"

Next i

End With
```

I am failing in the part

```
=.Cells(i, 2).Value2+1
```

I know I'm writing it wrong. But that's the way I want the code to work.

Please excuse if I'm not putting the question correctly. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Cells(j, 2).Value2 = "=.Cells(i, 2).Value2+1"
```

remove the double-quotes and the extra equals. That makes it a string, rather than evaluating the expression.

Comment: Just tried running it without quotes. 

    .Cells(j, 2).Value2 = =.Cells(i, 2).Value2+1

Gives syntax error.

Comment: ..and the extra equals sign.